# How to get application name in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, application-name

Sometimes we need to get app name in WPF programmatically i.e.

```
icon.UriSource = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/AppName;component/Images/logo.ico");
```

How we can do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One approach would be:

```
icon.UriSource = new Uri(string.Format(
    "pack://application:,,,/{0};component/Images/logo.ico",
    Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(Application.ResourceAssembly.Location)));
```